# Changing the construction of std::array

Tags: arrays, c++11, constructor

I'd like to change the construction of `std::array<unsigned int, size>` the following way:

- `myarray a {};` should construct `[0,1,2,3,4...]` instead of `[0,0,0,0,...]`
- `myarray a {5,2};` should construct `[5,2,2,3,4...]` instead of `[5,2,0,0,0...]`

One obvious solution is to have a class:

```
template <size_t size>
struct myarray {
    std::array<int, size> ar;
    myarray() { for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) ar[i]=i; }
    myarray(std::initializer_list<unsigned int> il) :ar(il) {
        for (size_t i=il.size(); i<size; i++) ar[i]=i; 
    } 
    ...
};
```

However it forces me to wrap every single member of `ar`. As far as I understand, inheriting from `std::array` is not a very good idea. Is there a third reasonable way ?

Comment: `my_make_array(std::initializer_list<T>)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 : Are you suggesting some kind of factory function ? Then how do you ensure that the array is always constructed trough this function ? I don't want a user to call the usual constructor inadvertently.

Comment: Yes I suggested a factory function. But it seems that it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my earlier post on the similar topic would be useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21651027/2724703

Comment: So you are saying that there is no critical problem inheriting form `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a very bad idea to change it globally. For all you know, `std::cout` internally uses a `std::array`. Even in your own code, the principle of least surprise dictates that `std::array<int, 5>` creates `[0,0,0,0,0]`. That's the whole point of `std::` - "STandarD".

So, the proper solution is to use a function which returns an array constructed like you want.

BTW, you can replace the `for`-loop with a single call to `std::iota(begin(ar)+il.size(), end(ar), il.size())`